# MySQL - Exceeding VARCHAR length from SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, varchar

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(fullname) SEPARATOR ';')AS "FULLNAMES"
  FROM Users;
```

I want to retrieve the fullnames of Users in a single row. However, the statement gives an incomplete result returning only the first 254 characters.

Is it possible to surpass this limitation?

Some might suggest to use the statement below instead and iterate through the result in my application but there's something that I would like to know.

```
SELECT DISTINCT fullname
  FROM Users;
```

Comment: `SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] group_concat_max_len = val;`

Comment: Do I have to restart the database for the changes to take effect? (Sorry if I didn't try before I asked. Someone is using the same instance as mine)

Comment: I think it's at the session level, so you don't need to worry about other people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adjusting the value of [`group_concat_max_len`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len)